Interpolation over a sequence of quaternions
I am trying to interpolate over a sequence of rotations represented by quaternions.
I am currently employing Squad (Spherical and Quadrangle Interpolation). I successfully applied the function to 4 rotations and the results corresponded to the expected one.
I would like to generalize the technique to an arbitrary (t>4) number of rotations.
In Quaternions, Interpolation and Animation, on page 54, it is hinted that Squad can be applied to any sequence of rotations.
Squad is defined as: $$Squad(q_i, q_{i+1}, s_i, s_{i+1}, t) := Slerp(Slerp(q_i, q_{i+1}, t), Slerp(s_i, s_{i+1}, t), 2t(1-t))$$
Support rotations are defined as:$$s_i := q_i\cdot exp{\Big(-{\frac{\log(q_i^{-1}\cdot\log(q_{i-1})) + \log(q_i^{-1}\cdot q_{i+1})}{4}}\Big)}$$
The report continues stating that supports should be enhanced as follows: $$s_0 = q_0; s_n = q_n$$
If I understood correctly, computing support rotations and invoking Squad with the corresponding four quaternions is sufficient.
For each quaternion i in the range [1..n-2] I compute the corresponding s_i.
At interpolation time I map the t parameter to the sequence of rotation and identify an i index, I remodulate the t parameter and eventually invoke $$Squad(q_i, q_{i+1}, s_i, s_{i+1}, t)$$
No need to say I implemented this technique but the results are wrong.
I double-checked my implementation of Slerp, I tested log(), exp(), and other quaternion methods, but they all seem to be correct. I concluded I didn't understand how to employ the technique, so I am asking for advice here.
Do you see any flaw in the reasoning I have just shown?
Edit: I am sharing part of the code, perhaps the problem is strictly practical.
Slerp:
static Quaternion Slerp(Quaternion &lhs, Quaternion &rhs, float t, TM_BOOL invert = true) {
    t = Unit(t);    // Clamps in range 0..1.
    if (t < 1e-20)
        return lhs;
    if (t > 1.0 - 1e-20)
        return rhs;
    if (lhs == rhs)
        return lhs;
    if (lhs == -rhs)
        return lhs;
    float dot = lhs.dot(rhs);
    if (abs(dot) >= 0.9999999) {
        if (dot >= 0.0)
            return Lerp(lhs, rhs, t).normalize();
        else
            return Lerp(lhs, -rhs, t).normalize();
    } else {
        float tetha = acos(dot);
        if (!invert)
            return (lhs * sin(tetha * (1.0 - t)) + rhs * sin(tetha * t)) / sin(tetha);
        else {
            if (dot >= 0.0)
                return (lhs * sin(tetha * (1.0 - t)) + rhs * sin(tetha * t)) / sin(tetha);
            else
                return (lhs * sin(tetha * (1.0 - t)) + (-rhs) * sin(tetha * t)) / sin(tetha);
        }
    }
}

Squad:
static Quaternion Squad(
    Quaternion &start,
    Quaternion &end,
    Quaternion &firstSupport,
    Quaternion &secondSupport,
    float t
) {
    t = Unit(t);
    return Slerp(
        Slerp(start, end, t, false),
        Slerp(firstSupport, secondSupport, t, false),
        2.0 * t * (1.0 - t),
        false
    );
}

Squad with support:
static Quaternion Squad(
    Quaternion &q0,
    Quaternion &q1,
    Quaternion &q2,
    Quaternion &q3,
    float t
) {
    q1 = (q0 + q1).squaredMagnitude() < (q0 - q1).squaredMagnitude() ? -q1 : q1;
    q2 = (q1 + q2).squaredMagnitude() < (q1 - q2).squaredMagnitude() ? -q2 : q2;
    q3 = (q2 + q3).squaredMagnitude() < (q2 - q3).squaredMagnitude() ? -q3 : q3;

    Quaternion
        firstSupport = Support(q0, q1, q2),
        secondSupport = Support(q1, q2, q3);

    return Squad(q0, q3, firstSupport, secondSupport, t);
}

Support:
inline static Quaternion Support(
    Quaternion &previous,
    Quaternion &current,
    Quaternion &next
) {
    Quaternion
        inverseOfQuat = current.inverse(),
        leftProduct = inverseOfQuat * previous,
        rightProduct = inverseOfQuat * next,
        leftLog = leftProduct.log(),
        rightLog = rightProduct.log(),
        sum = leftLog + rightLog,
        param = -sum / 4.0,
        result = current * param.exp();
    return result;
}

Rotation Sequence C'tor:
RotationSequence(
    std::vector<Quaternion> rotations
)  {
    if (rotations.size() < 4)
        throw std::runtime_error("Rotation sequence requires at least four rotations.");
    for (Quaternion rotation : rotations)
        this->rotations.push_back(rotation);
    /* Copy the last position to force the interpolation to behave correctly. */
    this->rotations.push_back(rotations[rotations.size() - 1]);
    /* Preprocesses the sequence, selectively negating all quaternions. */
    for (size_t ui = 1; ui < this->rotations.size(); ui++)
        if (this->rotations[ui].dot(this->rotations[ui - 1]) < 0.0)
            this->rotations[ui].negate();
    /* Compute supports for the whole sequence, 0-th and n-th correspond to quaternions 0-th and n-th. */
    supports.push_back(this->rotations[0]);
    for (size_t ui = 1; ui <= this->rotations.size()-2; ui++)
        supports.push_back(
            Support(
                this->rotations[ui - 1],
                this->rotations[ui + 0],
                this->rotations[ui + 1]
            )
        );
    supports.push_back(rotations[rotations.size() - 1]);

Interpolation:
Quaternion Interpolate(
    float t
) {
    t = Unit(t);
    /* Here, I identify the corresponding rotation by the $t$ factor. */
    float progress = float(rotations.size() - 2) * t;
    size_t ui = size_t(floor(progress));
    t = progress - float(ui);
    assert(ui + 0 < rotations.size());
    assert(ui + 1 < rotations.size());
    return Squad(
        rotations[ui],
        rotations[ui + 1],
        supports[ui],
        supports[ui + 1],
        t
    );
}


What's the standard against which you're comparing the output of your function?

I apply this technique in a simulation engine I am designing, I rotate my camera employing interpolated rotations.
Interpolants are camera orientations that are picked first and then employed.
When the function works correctly, I have a camera that smoothly points to intermediate points passing through all interpolants.
To be precise, I am only visually validating the output.

It might be useful to share your code, to see if we can spot any implementation issue.

I update the question. When I invoke Squad with support, I get exactly the interpolation I expect from a camera. The same holds for Slerp.

The mod expression looked a bit funny to me — do you observe any differences if you use this instead?
Quaternion Interpolate(
    float t
) {
    t = Unit(t);

    float progress = float(rotations.size() - 1) * t;
    size_t ui = size_t(progress);
    assert(ui + 1 < rotations.size() - 1);

    t = progress - float(ui);

    return Squad(
        rotations[ui],
        rotations[ui + 1],
        supports[ui],
        supports[ui + 1],
        t
    );
}

I think you also need some handling for the case when the input t == 1, since that should be a valid place to query the interpolation (it should just return the final quaternion), but with this code it will trip your assert.

You did it!
I removed the assertion and the interpolation is going smoothly!
Accepted!

Now, I need to figure why it is working.

The original code pinged my "fencepost error" spidey-sense. Interpolating a sequence of n quaternions is like building a fence with n posts. You need to join those posts with n - 1 spans. Your original mod code was using n in the denominator instead of n - 1. But since you'd already calculated both the continuous and integer parts of the progress value in earlier steps, we can extract our fractional progress to the next integer by just subtracting them, with no mod required.

I worked around the exception due to t being 1.0. I simply copy the last rotation twice and force the interpolation to reach size() - 2.
